# Hide tabs on woocommerce product editor for user role

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, tabs

I need help how to hide custom product data tabs (created by plugins) for custom user role on product page editor (see image).

[image]

I think it suppose to be done by modifying its CSS and apply it on functions.php

Already try and play with the below code and add the element in it, but not working.

```
// Remove Product Data Tabs Options on product page editor
add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs' , 'hide_wc_product_tabs' );

function hide_wc_product_tabs($tabs) {

  if (!current_user_can('yith_vendor')) {  // replace role ID with your own
      return $tabs;
  }

  //what code should I implement here

  return $tabs;
}
```

Any help appreciate. thank you

Comment: Which plugin is used for custom product data tabs? So I can clearly understand and will help you.

Comment: what @Karun said below solved the problem but not all, the tab created by plugin should be hide is Epeken and the additional extra tab created by the theme.

Comment: Can you please let me know theme name or give me website URL. So I can check it.

Comment: Here is the theme link https://themeforest.net/item/flatsome-multipurpose-responsive-woocommerce-theme/5484319

Answer (score 1):

So using your code as reference, you could do something like:

```
function hide_wc_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'yith_vendor' ) ) {
        return $tabs;
    }

    unset( $tabs['inventory'] ); // Removes the inventory tab.

    return $tabs;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_tabs' , 'hide_wc_product_tabs' );
```

These are the default WooCommerce product tabs:

```
Array ( [0] => general [1] => inventory [2] => shipping [3] => linked_product [4] => attribute [5] => variations [6] => advanced )
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I get it, but what I need to hide additional custom tabs created by specific plugins. I think it suppose to be done by modifying its CSS and apply it in the code.

Comment: @jasaweb You can do what @Karun suggested in his answer, do a `var_dump($tabs)` so you can see what is the key for each tab, and then unset what you don't need.

Comment: @jasaweb So you can add  this line before that unset: `var_dump( array_keys( $tabs ) );`

It will print the "name" for all the tabs that are available, then you can `unset` the ones you want to.

Comment: ok going to try

Answer (score 0):

The `$tabs` will return an array. Before the line `return $tabs;` you should check the key in the array and unset it. You can use `var_dump` to check what the array contains if you're unsure of the key name.

Comment: thanks, it works but I only got one key name from the tabs, how to get the other tabs key name?

Comment: `$tabs` should return all the available keys. Try increasing the priority value on `add_filter` and keep on debugging using `var_dump`

Comment: still no luck after increasing the priority value. any other method?